# Does java have some convention to indicate that object is in empty state?

Tags: java, oop

Of course, *empty* definition can differ. I'm used to PHP's empty though, which calls empty everything that evaluates to false. I'd like to call these things empty in my Java application:

- `null`
- String of zero `length`
- 0 `Integer`, `Float` or `Double`
- `false`
- Any array of zero length
- Empty `ArrayList` or `HashMap`

Java has, for example, `toString` convention. Every object is granted to give you some string representation. In my `Settings` class I operate with `HashMap<String, Object>`. My `empty` method looks now like this:

```
  public boolean empty(String name) {
    Object val = settings.get(name);
    if(val!=null) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

I'd like to extend it in a conventional manner, rather than `if(val instanceof XXX)` chain.

Comment: This isn't possible in Java. Also, Java doesn't have *empty* values but default values for primitive types and `null` as the default value for object references. String is a class, so a variable of type String will be a reference type and it's default value will be `null` as well, not an empty nor a blank string.

Comment: It would be more useful to have a method which does something specific for a specific type.  If the code is too abstract it becomes meaningless.  What is an actual use case you need such a method for?

Comment: I was asking for convention. There are many classes that have no intuitive string version - but they still posess the `toString` method.

Comment: @TomášZato toString() is for debugging/logging purposes. It is not intended to be used in code as such, just for giving something human readable.

Comment: @PeterLawrey In PHP, `empty` is ocassionally also counter-intuitive. But in the case of settings, it can cover `>50%` cases of checking the value. Therefore it makes production code shorter.

Comment: They have the `toString` method because it's inherited from `Object` class and all classes inherit from `Object`. You should not trust in the default implementation of `toString` method to check if the object is *empty*.

Comment: Although, both String and Collection have an `isEmpty()` method, `Number` classes don't.

Comment: Trying to write Java like it's PHP probably won't end well.  _When in Rome..._ and all that.

Comment: PHP is dynamically typed, and in an extremely annoying way. Java is statically typed. A variable either holds an object, or it holds null. Unless it is a primitive, which holds either 0 or false.

Comment: I kindly suggest you to stop thinking how you may solve this problem in PHP and try to port this knowledge into Java. Instead, learn some Java basics and try to think on how would you solve this problem using Java. PHP experience may help you with some details, but essentially they're two different programming languages with different structure.

Comment: @TomášZato settings are usually just a String value in Java.  You can check for not present or `isEmpty()`  It is not going to be another type unless you convert it to that type.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom stealing ideas from other languages isn't bad in my opinion.

Comment: Java and PHP are two totally different beast. You wouldn't fly an airplane like you drive a car, even though both are vehicles

Comment: @TomášZato stealing good ideas is a good option.  Trying to define a notion of "empty" if it maps to false sounds like a hack rather than a sensible idea.

Comment: Hack as in syntactically cumbersome and working against Java's designed-in ability to pick up common errors at compile time.

Comment: Java doesn't seem like a language that picks up errors at compile time with it's exceptions (and unreported exceptions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use overloading to describe all the "empty" objects:

```
public static boolean empty(Object o) {
  return o == null;
}

public static boolean empty(Object[] array) {
  return array == null || array.length == 0;
}
public static boolean empty(int[] array) { //do the same for other primitives
  return array == null || array.length == 0;
}

public static boolean empty(String s) {
  return s == null || s.isEmpty();
}

public static boolean empty(Number n) {
  return n == null || n.doubleValue() == 0;
}

public static boolean empty(Collection<?> c) {
  return c == null || c.isEmpty();
}

public static boolean empty(Map<?, ?> m) {
  return m == null || m.isEmpty();
}
```

Examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Object o = null;
  System.out.println(empty(o));
  System.out.println(empty(""));
  System.out.println(empty("as"));
  System.out.println(empty(new int[0]));
  System.out.println(empty(new int[] { 1, 2}));
  System.out.println(empty(Collections.emptyList()));
  System.out.println(empty(Arrays.asList("s")));
  System.out.println(empty(0));
  System.out.println(empty(1));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no standard convention for this in Java. Also, in Java there is no such thing as "evaluate to false" (except for booleans and Booleans, of course).

You will have to write a method (or rather, a series of overloaded methods for each type you need it for) which implements your notion of "empty". For example:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String s) {
    return (s == null) || (s.isEmpty());
}

public static boolean isEmpty(int i) {
    return i == 0;
}

...
```

Comment: All these suggestions however disregard the fact that `HashMap` gives me `Object`. I would have to find the deepest subtype of the object first. I don't even know if this is possible.

Comment: Why does HashMap give you `Object`? Generics are there since Java 1.5. `HashMap<String,String>` gives you `String`s, for example. But that aside, the answer remains: no Java does not offer a method for this and there is no standard convention. If you only have an `Object`, then yes, you must write a lot of `instanceof` code to determine the type of the object.

Comment: Actually, even if the second type is something else than `Object`, `Object` is what the `.getValue()` returns - explicit cast is needed.

Comment: You could define an abstract classes the implements `isEmpty(ClassName instance)` and inherit from that, but Java has no standard notion of empty. Strings happen to define `isEmpty` but that has a specific meaning; there is no notion of an empty `Integer` or `Long`.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no such convention. It's fairly common to see project specific utility classes with methods such as:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String s) {
    return s == null || s.isEmpty();
}
```

However I personally think its use is a bit of a code smell in Java. There's a lot of badly written Java around, but well written Java shouldn't need null checks everywhere, and you should know enough about the type of an object to apply type-specific definitions of "empty".

The exception would be if you were doing reflection-oriented code that worked with Object variables who's type you don't know at compile time. That code should be so isolated that it's not appropriate to have a util method to support it.

Python's duck-typing means the rules are sort of different.

Comment: Empty isn't here for null check but to check whether the value is suitable for being, for example, printed out.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to establish the notion of *emptiness* but it's not standardized across all Java classes. For example, the `Map` (implementation) provides the `Map#containsKey()` method to check if a key exists or not. The `List` and `String` (implementations) provide the `isEmpty()` method but the `List` or `String` reference itself could be `null` and hence you cannot avoid a `null` check there.

You could however come up with a utility class of your own that takes an `Object` and using `instanceof` adapts the `empty` checks accordingly.

```
public final class DataUtils {

    public static boolean isEmpty(Object data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (data instanceof String) {
            return ((String) data).isEmpty();
        }
        if (data instanceof Collection) {
            return ((Collection) data).isEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Guava Libraries](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Defaults.html) already contains Defaults class that do just that.

Calling defaultValue will return the default value for any primitive type (as specified by the JLS), and null for any other type.

You can use it like shown below:

```
import com.google.common.base.Defaults;
Defaults.defaultValue(Integer.TYPE); //will return 0
```

Below is example code on how to use it:

```
import com.google.common.base.Defaults;

public class CheckingFieldsDefault
{
    public static class MyClass {
      private int x;
      private int y = 2;
    }

    public static void main() {
       MyClass my = new MyClass();
       System.out.println("x is defualt: " + (my.x == Defaults.defaultValue(box(my.x).TYPE)));
       System.out.println("y is defualt: " + (my.y == Defaults.defaultValue(box(my.y).TYPE)));
    }

    private static <T extends Object> T box(T t) {
      return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only compare the primitive types value. For a specific object you will need to write its specific method.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an interface EmptinessComparable or something similar, and having all your classes implement that? So you can just expect that, and not have to ask instanceof every time.

Comment: Most settings will be integers and strings. The class that has that method is mostly just HashMap full of these.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not, but Groovy does. Groovy runs on the Java VM alongside Java code and provides many shortcuts and convenient conventions such as this. A good approach is write foundation and crital project components in Java and use Groovy for less critical higher level components.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the one approach, I would overload a utility method:

```
public class MyUtils {
    public static boolean isEmpty(String s) {
        return s == null || s.isEmpty();
    }
    public static boolean isEmpty(Boolean b) {
        return b == null || !b;
    }
    // add other versions of the method for other types
}
```

Then your code always looks like:

```
if (MyUtils.isEmpty(something))
```

If the type you're checking isn't supported, you'll get a compiler error, and you can implement another version as you like.